# Manually edit Glassfish Server Path settings

Tags: glassfish

I added several JARs to my GlassFish server path and now the GlassFish Admin Console won't come up.  It says "HTTP Status 404 - Servlet FacesServlet is not available".  I think something I added is causing a JAR conflict with the admin tool.  I would like to remove the stuff I added to the path, but I can't use the GlassFish admin tool to do it.

Can someone tell me how to manually edit the GlassFish server path values?  Are they stored in a XML file somewhere?  I looked around a little and couldn't find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem JAR (xercesImpl.jar).  If I simply rename that JAR, then the GlassFish Admin Console comes up with no problem.  Apparently GlassFish uses a different version and there was a conflict.